# Adding Vendor Id on linux for device debugging : error: no permissions

Tags: android, android-emulator, ubuntu-11.04

I am trying to add my Alcatel device on linux environment using this [link](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=660601)

Problem: not able to debug using this device

```
./adb devices
List of devices attached
????????????    no permissions
```

Followed this procedure:

1. `sudo gedit etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
2. Added this line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb" , ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6" , ATTRS{idProduct}=="9018" , MODE="0666"
```

But still it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the problem :

1. sudo gedit etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
2. Added this line

   SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6",ATTRS{idProduct}=="9018",MODE="0666"
3. sudo etc/init.d/udev restart

Note : Removed space between "," and restarted .

Comment: Thank you. Lots of examples to copy paste includes spaces, and removing them made the rule works!